# Fetch only last matched row from joined table in Laravel 8 eloquent using table join

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables `booking_orders(id)` and `booking_order_status_history(id, order_id,status, created_at)`
where `booking_order_status_history.order_id = booking_orders.id` There might be more than one rows having same order_id but i need to fetch the latest one. I am using laravel eloquent query

```
BookingOrders::select("booking_orders.*", "booking_order_status_history.status as status")
  ->join('booking_order_status_history', 'booking_order_status_history.order_id', '=', 'booking_orders.id'))
->get()
```

This is loading all rows from saveral matched rows at booking_order_status_history.

How can i fetch the last inserted `status` row only. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on retrieving all the results using exactly one query, with joins, you can use this query:

```php
 BookingOrder::query()
            ->join('booking_order_status_history', 'booking_order_status_history.order_id', '=', 'booking_order_status_history.order_id')
            ->where('booking_order_status_history.id', '=', DB::raw("select MAX(booking_order_status_history.id) from booking_order_status_history where booking_order_status_history.order_id = booking_orders.id"))
            ->get();
```

But I totally encourage you to use laravel eloquent relationship solutions , which of course costs you an extra query. But brings clean code.

```php
// Define Orders Model
class BookingOrder extends Model
{
    public function latestStatus()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(BookingOrderStatusHistory::class)->latestOfMany();
    }
}
```

```php
// Define History Model
class BookingOrderStatusHistory extends Model
{
    //
}
```

```php
// Retrieve data in controller
$orders = BookingOrder::query()->with('latestStatus')->get();

foreach ($orders as $order){
    echo $order->latestStatus->status;
}
```